# Html file also opens a picture?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm on a mac, and when I double-click the html file, it opens a photo that I'm using in Preview. If I "open with" Google Chrome, then the picture opens in it's own tab. The html file itself loads and functions correctly, and the picture appears just as it should. I just have NO CLUE why it also opens the picture file in a new tab(Chrome) or Preview(safari).

html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='style.css'/>
    <script src="jQuery.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id=top>
        <h1>Lamborghini</h1>
    </div>

    <div id=navbar>
            <div id=navlink> <a href="Made.html">Home</a> </div>
            <div id=navlink> <a href="Made.html">Photos</a> </div>
            <div id=navlink> <a href="Made.html">Videos</a> </div>
            <div id=navlink> <a href="Made.html">About Us</a> </div>
            <div id=navlink> <a href="Made.html">Contact</a> </div>
    </div>

    <div>
        <div id=leftpanel></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Javascript

```
if(typeof jQuery === "undefined")
    {console.log("jQuery is not loaded.")}
else
    {console.log("jQuery is loaded.")}

$(document).ready(
    $(document).scroll(
        function()
            {$("div").fadeTo(1000,1)}
        )
    );
```

I'm doing everything locally (just a beginner learning), and I have a jQuery database linked. Not sure if any of that is important.

CSS

```
body
    {opacity:0}

.fade2
    {opacity:1;
    position:fixed;
    z-index:-1;
    width:100%;
    opacity:0}

div#navbar
    {height:50px;
    width:100%;
    opacity:0;
    border-radius:7px;
    background-color:rgba(0,150,255,0.8);
    margin:auto;
    overflow:hidden}

div#navlink:hover
    {background-color:rgba(0,105,180,0.6)}

div#navlink
    {width:20%;
    display:inline-block;
    border:1px solid black;
    height:100%;
    margin:0;
    float:left;
    text-align:center;
    box-sizing:border-box;}

a
    {text-decoration:none;
    color:white;
    position:relative;}

#top
    {text-align:center;
    height:544px;
    background:url("Lambo2.jpg") bottom no-repeat;
    background-size:100%;
    background-color:white;
    margin:0px;
    margin-top:-45px;
    width:100%;
    background-color:transparent;
    opacity:0.9}

h1
    {position:relative;
    font-size:4em;
    top:.38em;
    color:black;
    font-family:cursive;
    text-align:left}


#leftpanel
    {height:1000px;
    width:45%;
    margin-left:4%;
    margin-top:1%;
    float:left;
    background-color:rgba(0,150,255,1);
    opacity:0}

span
    {position:relative;
    top:1em}
```

Comment: I don't see anything in your code attempting to show an image?

Comment: This has nothing to do with your code. You're somehow opening both files at once in your finder.

Comment: I forgot to paste the css. And the issue stopped on its own. I have no clue.

Comment: And thanks for clearing that up, Andy. That's really what I was wondering: whether or not it was related to the code. You have any idea how something like that could happen?

Comment: if it stopped 'on its own', probably something you were somehow doing and not noticing. Otherwise, I'd suspect something in script.js. Unless that script is all of script.js.

Comment: Yeah, that's all the script. I must have been doing something. Oh well. =/